# JSF doesn't generate HTML output, instead plain JSF source code is visible in HTML output

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

I'm doing my Course Final Assignment and I'm having some issues with JSF and HTML5. Before ask this, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828788/java-ee-6-jsf-2-with-html-pages-instead-of-xhtml) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980040/jsf-page-not-rendering-as-html) answer.

In my project settings (Properties -> Project Facets) I have:

- Java: 1.6
- Dynamic Web Project: 2.5
- JSF: 2.0 (Mojarra 2.0.3)

I created my HTML5 files separeted, and now I want merge my Java software with my front-end code. But I'm having issues, JSF don't render .html files.

Here's my original HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Fernando Paladin">
        <title>Locus - Disciplinas </title>

        <link href="../../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 center">
                    <h:form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <h:inputText id="disciplina" class="form-control" value="#{disciplinaMBean.nome}" />
                                <!--  <input type="text" size="20" class="form-control" id="disciplina" placeholder="Pesquise ou crie uma nova disciplina" 
                                required>  -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <h:commandButton class="btn btn-md btn-success" action="#{disciplinaMBean.cadastrar}">
                                    Adicionar
                                </h:commandButton>
                                <!--  <a type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Adicionar</a> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <br/>
                                <h:dataTable value="#{disciplinaMBean.listaDisciplinas}" var="disciplina">
                                    <h:column>
                                        <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{disciplinaMBean.nome}" />
                                    </h:column>
                                </h:dataTable>
                                <!-- <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Aqui vão ser carregadas as disciplinas" rows="5"></textarea> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <!-- JavaScripts e Complementos -->
        <script src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

And this is what's rendered:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Fernando Paladin">
    <title>Locus - Disciplinas </title>

    <link href="../../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 center">
                <h:form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <h:inputText id="disciplina" class="form-control" value="#{disciplinaMBean.nome}" />
                            <!--  <input type="text" size="20" class="form-control" id="disciplina" placeholder="Pesquise ou crie uma nova disciplina" 
                            required>  -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <h:commandButton class="btn btn-md btn-success" action="#{disciplinaMBean.cadastrar}">
                                Adicionar
                            </h:commandButton>
                            <!--  <a type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Adicionar</a> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <br/>
                            <h:dataTable value="#{disciplinaMBean.listaDisciplinas}" var="disciplina">
                                <h:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{disciplinaMBean.nome}" />
                                </h:column>
                            </h:dataTable>
                            <!-- <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Aqui vão ser carregadas as disciplinas" rows="5"></textarea> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScripts e Complementos -->
    <script src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>

</h:body>
```

As you can see, my original file is the rendered file. So, I can't click in any field, can't type text in the input, ultimately, I can do nothing.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to invoke JSF's `FacesServlet`. It's the one responsible for that job. Look closer at the URL you typed in browser's address bar and make sure that it matches the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as you've definied in webapp's `web.xml`. Or, just change the `<url-pattern>` to `*.xhtml` (or `*.html`, if that's your physical file extension and you intend to run all `.html` URLs through JSF), so that you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs.

Please note that this problem has absolutely nothing to do with HTML5 as you originally complained.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)
- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - to learn the mandatory basics about servlets

Comment: Thanks BalusC, now this works! I just want know, don't have a way to do this from IDE? (I'm using eclipse). I say that because the answer of this question can help people. A lot of thanks for you!

Comment: You're welcome. As to your new question, I don't understand what you're asking there. "Have a way"? Just start the server and open the page/bookmark in your favourite webbrowser.

Comment: Sorry. When I configure my project in classroom, my teacher taught how to configure this <url-pattern> by a graphical way, without need to go in web.xml and edit this file. I wanted mean, a graphical way to configure web.xml.

Comment: Just doubleclick `web.xml` file and edit source code. No need to visually edit code. Just edit real code by text, otherwise you learn nothing.

Comment: Oh, you understood wrong :( Yes, you're right, forget what I try to mean. Damn language barrier! hahah. Bye, and thanks.